# Is there a simple Linq to SQL generator with bi-directional serialization attributes?

Tags: linq-to-sql, serialization, code-generation

I'm trying to find a way to generate Linq to SQL classes with bi-directional serialization attributes. Basically I want a DataMember tag (with an appropriate order) on every association property, not just the ones where the class is the primary key (like the Visual Studio generator and SQL Metal do). I checked MyGeneration, but didn't really find anything that worked for me. I thought the T4 Toolbox was going to be my solution, it would be quite easy to modify it to add the attributes, but I get an exception on the calling side of my WCF service, and I've gotten no response back on the issue. I'm about to try installing CodeSmith and using PLINQO, but I'd prefer something free.

I'm pretty close to just writing my own T4 generator, but before I do that, I was hoping to find an pre-built solution to this rather simple problem first.

Comment: I've just found this: http://tinyurl.com/ybxr2cp, which looks to be exactly what I need, but I'm experiencing some problems, described here: http://tinyurl.com/y8ptyzs. I think if I can get that resolved, I'll be well on my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) turned out to be the solution to my problem. I had just resigned myself to start researching my own generator when I stumbled upon that. It has a bidirectional serialization option and it works great! [Here's a link to the author's bog](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/01/19/linq-to-sql-templates-updated-now-on-codeplex), which contains a great video example of how to get started.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing my own code generator for our L2S classes. We actually generate two sets of classes. One is a "lightweight" set of entities for client application use. These classes have no L2S plumbing. But they have the full datamember attributes with proper order. Then we have our L2S entities, which are strictly for backend use. This has worked out quite well.

Be careful using PLINQO. I've looked at that product extensively. In fact, much of my code generator is based on the code PLINQO generates. However, they have a "major flaw" (their words) in how they have implemented many to many relationships.

You might want to also look at a product named "Reegenerator".

Randy

Comment: The major flaw you refer to is not with PLINQO's Many-To-Many implementation. It has to do with Microsoft's closed source Linq-to-SQL implementation in specific areas where PLINQO can't do advanced features like Future queries with Many-To-Many's because there is no access to the internal Linq-To-SQL information that is needed.

Comment: @Blake - The problem is indeed with PLINQO's M:M implementation. I was told specifically by them they had a "significant" design flaw in their M:M implementation and they could not give me any sort of date when it might be fixed. The generated code is buggy. You cannot blame this on Microsoft's 'closed system'.

Comment: If we cannot modify how the run-time handles many to many than there isn't much we can do in this situation. If you have a work around that works for many-to-many's we would love to hear it. Also, if you can point out what specific generated code is buggy we would love to fix it.